# If $\{ e_1, ..., e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, show that $\{T(e_1), ..., T(e_n)\}$ is a basis for $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T: V \rightarrow W $ be an injective linear transformation, where $V, W$ are vector spaces of dimension $n$ over the field $\mathbb{K}$. If $\{ e_1, ..., e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, show that $\{T(e_1), ..., T(e_n)\}$ is a basis for $W$.

What I'm thinking is the solution:

Since $T$ is an injective function, that means no two $v \in V$ will map to the same $w \in W$. Hence, each $ t \in \{T(e_1), ..., T(e_n)\}$ is distinct to each other. As $V$ is linearly independent, then all $t$ are linearly independent to each other as well, which forms the basis of $W$.

Comment: You need to show that the $Te_k$ are linearly independent & span $W$. You have done neither.

Comment: You have to show $Ker(V)=\{0\}$ for injectivity. Epimorphsms preserve the spanning sets. In this case, you have an isomorphism.

Comment: Showing that the $Te_k$ are linearly independent is straightforward. Then since there are $n$ of them. it must be a basis.